# How to remove horizontal and vertical lines on image using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, horizontal-line

I am new to python. I have to remove horizontal and vertical lines on my graph image using opencv and python. Here is my image. This is a graph containing a curve, I want to compare different curves but not the grid:

[image: This is a graph containing a curve, I want to compare different curves but not the grid]

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [opencv tutorial] (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html)

Comment: I try my best, and get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0xbr.png. Basic steps include: （1）threshold，(2) morph with different kernel, (3) bitwise_op, (4) filte by area, (5) mask op.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got confused before, when selecting a correct method for this. I tried                                                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461211/how-to-remove-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-from-an-image?rq=1                                                                             https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html                    but nothing could achive this much accuracy. Thank you vermuch again.

Comment: @Mark Setchell , Can you explain the steps little bit more.