# Remove a merged line from image OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to identify the text on an image that is merged with 2 pieces. The image has the merged line on it. Is there a way to remove the merge line? to identify the text on it.

**this is my image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, it is possible to remove that line but you may have to work a bit harder. The first task is to identify lines. For this, you may use [Houge Transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) or [RANSAC](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) or any other techniques. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838156/python-opencv-houghlinesp-fails-to-detect-lines) might be helpful for you as well. I would suggest you start with Houge because of lines in your cause has some definite angles which might be easier to detect lines. Then you need to apply some [morphological operation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) like erosion and dilation for smoothing the image. Also, have a look [structural analysis and shape descriptors](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponents) to reduce the false positive and false negative detections. Work on this way and if something not clear, ask again.